# Array.push is in Array but $.inArray returns "false"

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to add the first ones values to the second one. I achieved this with `.push`.

Array initialization:

```
<script>
var needsPrecision = ["Decimal"];
var needsLength = ["Binary", "Char", "NChar", "NVarChar", "VarBinary", "VarChar"];
needsLength.push(needsPrecision);
```

After this I looped them through and `"Decimal"` was in the `needsLength` array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < needsLength.length; i++) {
    alert (needsLength[i]);
}
alert("---");
for (var i = 0; i <needsPrecision.length; i++) {
    alert(needsPrecision[i]);
}
```

But if I check it (in `$(document).ready()`), it's returning `-1` -> `false`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($.inArray("Decimal", needsLength));
}
</script>
```

Did I miss something with scopes? (Sorry I am very new to jquery)

Answer (score 1):

`needsPrecision` is an array. You need to [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the array's like following.

```
var needsPrecision = ["Decimal"];
var needsLength = ["Binary", "Char", "NChar", "NVarChar", "VarBinary", "VarChar"];
needsLength = needsLength.concat(needsPrecision);
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **spread syntax** to combine two arrays and then get the index:

```js
var needsPrecision = ["Decimal"];
var needsLength = ["Binary", "Char", "NChar", "NVarChar", "VarBinary"];
needsLength = [...needsLength, ...needsPrecision];
console.log(needsLength);
alert($.inArray("Decimal", needsLength));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can even use `Array.push.apply()` to combine the array and then get the index:

```js
var needsPrecision = ["Decimal"];
var needsLength = ["Binary", "Char", "NChar", "NVarChar", "VarBinary"];
needsLength.push.apply(needsLength, needsPrecision);
console.log(needsLength);
alert($.inArray("Decimal", needsLength));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```